# Capistrano deploy with gitosis and application server at the same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, gitosis

I build gitosis server and stage server on the same VPS server. Clone the repository from gitosis in my local machine or stage server are work well. But `cap deploy` in local machine always ask me input password as below, I have no idea which password is and I try every password all doesn't work.

And I know could copy local repository with `deploy_via: copy`, but I prefer build a gitosis server for the other projects.

Any ideas? thanks.

### environment

gitosis and stage server ip: `106.187.xxx.xxx` (mask some number for security reason)

### log

```
  * executing `deploy'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy'
  * executing `check:revision'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote gitosis@106.187.xxx.xxx:foo_project.git master"
    command finished in 1105ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/deployer/apps/railsapp/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/deployer/apps/railsapp/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 07827de89355c5366c4511ee22fdd9c68a31b0be && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q gitosis@106.187.xxx.xxx:foo_project.git /home/deployer/apps/railsapp/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/deployer/apps/railsapp/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 07827de89355c5366c4511ee22fdd9c68a31b0be; fi"
    servers: ["106.187.xxx.xxx"]
    [106.187.xxx.xxx] executing command
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out] Password:
Password: 
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out]
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out] Password:
Password: 
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out]
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out] Password:
Password: 
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out]
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out] Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
 ** [106.187.xxx.xxx :: out] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

#### deploy.rb

```
server "106.187.xxx.xxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "railsapp"
set :user, "deployer"
set :local_user, "joshchang"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"

set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "stage"

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "gitosis@106.187.xxx.xxx:foo_project.git"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, a little hard to understand the question, but there are two ways to use `git` within capistrano.  The first is to grant the server direct access to the git repository; on GitHub, for example, you have an option to install "deploy keys" -- the public key(s) of the server(s) that need access.  So check if gitosis has this option.

But before you do, consider the other approach, which is to pass the git authorization of the user doing the deploy, so when you deploy, you pull as yourself, rather than instructing the server to do so.  There are pros and cons to each method, but I think the second method is much easier to manage in the long run.

To use the second method, the machine of the person deploying (running capistrano) needs to 1) have `ssh-agent` running, and 2) needs to use `ssh-add` to authorize `ssh-agent` to use your public key -- it's very secure, and once you have it set up, it's transparent.

When you use the second method, access to git will be the same as it is locally, so shouldn't prompt for password.  Otherwise your settings in `deploy.rb` are fine as is.

Comment: hi @tharrison, I did ssh-agent in local, but the problem didn't solve. I found turn of the sshd in local will show error message like `ssh: connect to host $MY_LOCAL_IP port 22: Connection refused` and `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` when `cap deploy`. Is it necessary sshd should be turn on? thanks.

Comment: Before capistrano will work, you'll need to do two things, 1) ssh to the remote host using the `deployer` user, and 2) run an ssh command on the remote host that connects to the git repository via ssh.  You don't need sshd (the service/daemon) running locally, but it does need to be running on the remote host (and probably is).